# How can I change the project I upload to in GAE using maven?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

A while back, I created a GAE project using maven locally. First I created a remote project, and used the projectID while creating the local project to relate the local project with the remote one. I then used the `mvn appengine:update` command to upload the project, and opened the projectID.appspot.com to check, and everything worked correctly.

After some recent changes though, I wanted to change the target remote project, so I created a new project in Google Cloud Platform and in my local `appengine-web.xml` file, I changed the old projectID with the new one. I then tried `mvn appengine:update` again, to re-upload the project to the new location, and although it finished without promting any errors, it didn't work properly. When I tried to open the newProjectId.appspot.com page, the app didn't appear. Instead it only showed a page titled "App Engine Demo", with a "Hello, world" message. I checked the Activity tab of my new project in Google Cloud Platform and it shows the deployments, and also the cron jobs I created are running (100% errors though), but nothing seems to have been uploaded. What have I missed? Do I need to change anything else besides `appengine-web.xml` in order for the project to be correctly uploaded to the new location?

Comment: This should result in the outcome you're looking for. Double check the ids, make sure you have access, do a mvn clean appengine:update and see if it works. Then I would check the default version to ensure it matches what you just uploaded.

Comment: There are many possible variables. Did you run `mvn clean`? Did you deploy to the project you think you did (check pom.xml / appengine-web.xml)? Did you deploy to the current defeault service and version?

Answer (score 1):

If you created the new project using a different Google account, you need to delete `.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java` file so that it asks you for authorization again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice, unfortunately the new project was created using the same account.